# Data binding to EF entities or to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm

I have a WPF application with MVVM, Entity Framework and a WCF service.

I have created Self-Tracking Entities so the entity classes already implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
Should I databind the properties of these classes directly (for example having a `ObservableCollection<Author> Authors` property in my main ViewModel) or should I create a ViewModel with the same properties (and having `ObservableCollection<AuthorViewModel> Authors` property in the main ViewModel) ?

Another question, not related to the title, but well. 
Before using STE, I was using POCO classes for my entities, but they are not serializable and the the WCF service had trouble with that. Is there an easy solution ?

Comment: Why were your POCOs not serializable? All it should have taken is an atrribute or two.

Comment: Is it ok to modify the generated POCO classes ?

Comment: Better to modify the template that generates the POCOs to add the proper attribute(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended answer is to use `ObservableCollection<AuthorViewModel>`, mainly because if any additional UI-specific logic needs to be implemented then that logic should be in a ViewModel, not a Model. In my experience, it's always cleaner to wrap your model in a viewmodel, if only for consistency.

Comment: I agree with you wraping the model in your viewModel allows for the ability to make viewModel specific changes without modifying the Model (especially nice when the model is an EF POCO)